# Log4j 2 not logging with correct time in JAVA

Tags: java, asynchronous, logging, log4j2

I have written a basic Server that receives data from Client and processes the received messages. Whenever I am receiving I am logging the received messages into a log file. Now the problem is : all messages sent to the Server are logged at the Client side. Suppose a message sent from Client to Server at "18:32:23:345" then at my Server side when I am logging it is showing received at "18:32:23:300". Please observe the Milli-seconds time at the Server side. It is showing that the message is received before the message is sent. I am using Asynchronous logging with log4j2. Can anyone please help me.

This is my XML file of Log4j2 configuration at Server side:

```
<Configuration status="warn">
<Appenders>
    <File name="my_file_appender" fileName="Errors.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </File>
    <Async name="async_appender">
        <AppenderRef ref="my_file_appender" />
    </Async>
    <!-- file appender -->
    <RollingFile name="Error-log" fileName="MESSAGES.log"
                 filePattern="MESSAGES-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
        <!-- log pattern -->   
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <!-- set file size policy -->
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>   
</Appenders>   
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="Error-log" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="Error-log" level="debug"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="info" includeLocation="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="async_appender"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

As per my view the Client side logging is working perfectly. Is there any problem with my configuration? I have tried implementing the same configuration with .properties file. But it is not working. Can anyone also tell me how to change the above configuration to .properties file as loading XML every time makes my application to slow down. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure what client logging is meant here, however you will need to ensure that both your client and server are in sync w.r.t to their system clocks right up to the `milli-second` level. This will ensure correct time is getting logged.

Comment: Are client and server running on the same machine or on different machines?

Comment: Yes, they are running on the same machine : localhost